# How to retrive data from one table based on the condition from 2 other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've 3 tables

> 1.customer(cust_no, cust_name, place)
>
> 2.account(acc_no,cust_no, acc_type, balance, branchno)
>
> 3.branch(branch_no, place).

I tried this query to get data :

```
select CUST_NAME,PLACE 
FROM CUSTOMER c 
join account a on c.CUST_NO=a.CUST_NO 
join branch b on b.place=c.PLACE;
```

I need to display the names and place of customers who have account on their own place. how to do this using join

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: yes I do ' select CUST_NAME,PLACE FROM CUSTOMER c join account a on  c.CUST_NO=a.CUST_NO join branch b on b.LOCATION=c.PLACE;'

Comment: but it will show the entire customer names if any branch name matches with their place . I need to look around the branch code of the account for a particular customer, then the location of the corresponding branch code. and if the branch location is same as  the place of the customer it needs to be displayed

Comment: can you give sample output data? also in your query in the last join when you say `b.place`, do you mean `b.location` ?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your jointures normally, and then filter the places with a WHERE clause

```
SELECT c.CUST_NAME, c.PLACE 
FROM CUSTOMER c 
INNER JOIN account a on c.CUST_NO=a.CUST_NO 
INNER JOIN branch b on b.branch_no=a.branchno
WHERE b.place=c.PLACE
```

Comment: thanks . it worked... I was totally confused with the three tables.